# How to make LaTeX in org-msg e-mails look nice?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, mu4e, html

I just want to send nice-looking e-mails like this[image]

This e-mail is achieved by using Apple Mail, LaTeXiT and a bit of hand-waving. However, in org-msg mode I can by default with dvipng/imagemagick achieve such formatting
[image]

Or, with option image-size-adjust set to (1 . 0.4)
[image]

The question is what I should do to make org-msg e-mails look as nice as in the first picture? As I understood dvisvgm formatting of e-mails math can not be achieved, so all my examples use png formatting.

Nice formatting of first picture consists of

1. HiDPI resolution of embedded PNG math images.
2. Font size of math text in PNG pictures consistent with regular text around.

In contrast, on the second picture we see PNG probably of the same resolution as the first, but with big physical dimensions which implies low DPI + inconsistency with regular text font size.

And on the third we math images which are approximately consistent in font size with text around but with extremely low DPI.

The solution probably will be to somehow approach big resolution of exported images while keeping physical dimensions of math inside (keeping desired font size in other words). But I don't know how to do it in Emacs mail.

Comment: *"look as nice"* is vague. Please be (much) more specific. Just what are you requesting?

Comment: @Drew Sorry, nice math in this context means hidpi math with font size of non-math text around

Comment: Don't clarify in comments. Clarify the question itself. (And the comment itself isn't clear, to me at least.)

Comment: @Drew, thanks for feedback, done.